# Run Multiple PHP Websites On a Single Elastic Beanstalk Environment

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Trying to figure out how to run multiple PHP sites on a single EBS environment for a shared dev environment. Final production will have a dedicated EBS environment for each app but for the dev environment looking at a single shared environment as it will be very low traffic (only Devs accessing it) but wanting the dev hosting to match the prod hosting. Is this possible with Beanstalk natively or would I need to look at an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends really on how much traffic you will receive to this service, i understand that AWS EBS is designated for one site with high variants measure by requests so if you going to received a very low traffic i don't see why you want to use Beanstalk. Instead I'll use an instance on EC2 with reserved instances and a scale group with LAMP fully customizable or RDS (RDS with hight availability will be cheaper as in [this article describe](https://webscoot.io/blog/rds-vs-ec2-for-mysql/)) I'm running several instances with a very low price, i even have some t2.micro with RDS with around 100 to 200 simultaneous request and it is working like a charm. You can configure several virtual host in apache httpd.conf

Anyway, all depends of your special necessities but sometimes simple solution is the best.